# Add-member in iteration doesn't work in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Here is the code:

1. I get projects list
2. Iterate through the list and add member on the current value

**doesn't work**

```
[psobject] $tfs = get-tfs "http://myserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection"
[psobject] $projects = $tfs.CSS.ListAllProjects()

foreach($pro in $projects){
    $pro | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name TFS -value $tfs
    $test = $pro.TFS
}
```

Comment: My expected output is not just ProjectInfo with Name, Uri and Status. I would like to pass TFS instance with each project instance as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the `$tfs` object, why not just pass it with the `$projects` collection to whatever code you're calling after this?  That way you're only dealing with it once, rather than looping over all the projects and adding the same variable to each.  So something like this:

```
[psobject] $tfs = get-tfs "http://myserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection"
[psobject] $projects = $tfs.CSS.ListAllProjects()

myFunction $projects $tfs
```

Comment: Yes, that would fit, but I work mainly with PowerGUI. I've found out that this is worked out with SharedScript